# How to get characters before a specific character

Tags: r

How do I get the month from the below dates by just extracting all the characters left to the `/`.

Some example data:

```
10/1/2015 10:30:00
10/15/2015 13:32:00
2/12/2012
```

Comment: My solution was based on the description you provided i.e. to extract all elements before the `/`..

Comment: @akrun If you read the question, the goal is to get the months (which happens to be the number before the first `/`).

Comment: @Jaap You can get that in many ways as I have showed in my post.

Comment: @akrun True, both are valid answers imo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a combination of the functions `as.Date` and `months` for that. This will give you the names of the months:

```
months(as.Date(str1, format = "%m/%d/%Y"))
```

which gives:

```
[1] "October"  "October"  "February"
```

If you just want the number of the months, you can also use the `month` function from the `data.table` package:

```
library(data.table)
month(as.Date(str1, format = "%m/%d/%Y"))
```

which returns an integer vector:

```
[1] 10 10  2
```

---

Used data:

```
str1 <- c('10/1/2015 10:30:00', '10/15/2015 13:32:00', '2/12/2012')
```